Assigning default values to class objects when member functions don't exist
I realized I had oversimplified my earlier question while trying to make it easily reproducible.
What I want is to run a member function on that input value and assign the result to an attribute, but if the input value didn't have that function, to give a default value instead, i.e.:
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, random_object):
        self.name = random_object.getID() or "Dummy Value"
        self.score = random_object.getScore() or 0

If the random_object.getID() function doesn't exist, I get an AttributeError:
>>> p = Puzzle("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getID'

Is the only way to concisely do this a check for AttributeError? What if I have multiple things I want to assign like this?
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, random_object):
        try:
            self.name = random_object.getID()
            self.score = random_object.getScore()
        except AttributeError as att:
            if att.name == "getID":
                self.name = "Dummy Value"
            elif att.name == "getScore":
                self.score = 0

I think the above block will only be able to catch one of the exceptions and miss assigning the other value. How can I catch the rest?

One try for one call.

Thanks. I'm also kind of doing research and trying for solutions while I ask here, so if you could comment on the answer below, that would be nice, too.

What I've seen from this answer is to try  hasattr:
class Puzzle:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.name = obj.id if hasattr(obj, "id") else "Dummy"
        self.score = obj.score() if hasattr(obj, "score") else 0

That seems to work for me so far. Is there a more concise way, though?

I note an objection that it "uses try/except under the hood". If any answer or comment could also address whether this is still relevant, I'd appreciate it.

I agree with that objection. hasattr essentially retrieves value of an attribute and then discard it, which would be wasting as you need the value. Despite that, using a name in string form makes the code error prone and hard to refactor.

getattr supports default values so you can do something like self.name = getattr(obj, "id", "Dummy"); When the attribute in question is a function hasattr will look more readable but it is possible to use getattr like self.name = getattr(obj, "getID", lambda: "Dummy")()
